# How to convert Thévenin equivalent to Norton equivalent in this schematic?

Tags: power-electronics, impedance, matrix, equivalent-circuit

I am learning the  bus admittance matrix from *Power System Analysis* by Hadi Saadat electrical engineering. I have a very big problem in chapter 6.2 - *Bus Admittance Matrix*.

At the beginning of chapter 6.2 ,it shows me this diagram:

[image]

Then it says we redraw the circuit like this:

[image]

The problem I have is that I don't know how to redraw the first picture to the second picture. It seems it is the conversion of Thévenin equivalent to Norton equivalent,but I don't know how to convert this circuit. For example, in the position \$y34\$ ,the admittance become -j12.5 from j0.08.  Why?

Can anyone tell me? Is it important to know how to redraw the equivalent schematic when learning the bus admittance matrix?

Comment: Did you remember that 1/j=-j?

Comment: You _do_ realize that impedances have been converted to admittances going from Figure 6.1 to Figure 6.2 -- yes?  If you have an impedance \$Z\$, how do you get the corresponding admittance?